# AMD A8-3850  and Asus F1A75-M works well on Ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, ati, asus, amd-processor

I'm thinking about mount a new computer with a AMD A8-3850 processor and an Asus F1A75-M motherboard. I would like to know if both of them work well with Ubuntu 11.10, specially because the motherboard has UEFI technology and the processor has a integrated graphics unity (APU).

The 3D acceleration works well with Catalyst drivers?

I'll only use Ubuntu 11.10 (and Ubuntu 12.04 when it's released) no Windows at all, so it's crucial know if the motherboard and the processor (with video acceleration) works fine on Ubuntu.

Anyone has experience with these two components? Any info will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone owns this motherboard and processor, let me know how's your experience with both on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I may be difficult to get the answers you seek from this site unless you know the hardware involved in the specific models.

I would suggest checking the site out:
http://friendly.ubuntu.com/

There is an article on Phoronix that covers your CPU/APU - http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_a83850_cpu&num=1

The other place to check is on ubuntuforums.org

Comment: According to Phoronix article the APU unity works well in Ubuntu 11.04 with Catalyst Drivers, so it should be ok on 11.10 too. Also the processor was tested on a Asus F1A75-M Pro on OpenBenchmarking.org (http://openbenchmarking.org/s/A8-3850)  in several Ubuntu versions, so I believe that this combination works well. Thanks for your help cprofitt.